# How to save carry bits in 8085?

Tags: 8085

Suppose two 16bits numbers are added in 8085, then there is a carry, so, how do I save the carry into a memory location?

Comment: Add it to 0, just like every other platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JNC - Jump if not carry   use it to jump past code that stores some value in memory, or increments some register.

Comment: Oh, I see, so there's no direct instruction linking from flag to memory then?